# How can I collapse the overflow of row navigation links row into a drop-down menu button in the event of browser window size/width decrease?

Tags: html, css, overflow

In most websites, if you squeeze/reduce the width of browser window, the row of navigation links in the top navigation bar collapses into a drop-down menu button because of overflow. How can I add that feature to my website?

Currently, the overflowing links/buttons in my website just disappear if I reduce the size/width of my browser window. How can I use a drop-down menu button in case of overflow due to reduced width?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with media queries by targeting the max-with of desired-size like shown in the example if the size of the browser goes below 1700x its gonna change its flex-direction to column and change the height to auto.

```css
* {
      font-size:40px;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .navbar-nav{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 2rem;
        background-color: gray;
       
    }
    .nav-links{
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0.5rem;
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1700px){
        .navbar-nav{
            height: auto;
            flex-direction: column;
            background-color: gray;
            
    }
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-links">Home</li>
        <li class="nav-links">About</li>
        <li class="nav-links">Services</li>
        <li class="nav-links">Email</li>
        <li class="nav-links">Something</li>
        <li class="nav-links">SignUp</li>
        <li class="nav-links">Login</li>
        <li class="nav-links">Loremips</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </body>
```

Comment: Thank you. I've yet to learn media queries, but this solved the issue 